# Replacement for deprecated WebResourceLoadDelegate

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, osx-elcapitan

As of OS X 10.11 (or more specifically 10.10.3), all the methods on the [`WebResourceLoadDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/) protocol for WebKit have been deprecated. My application was making use of these delegate methods, and I'm wondering what a suitable replacement for them would be. I'm also be curious as to why they have been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`WebResourceLoadDelegate` *formal* protocol has been added in OS X 10.11 in favor of the deprecated `WebResourceLoadDelegate` *informal* protocol, though the reference hasn't been updated to reflect it yet. Use the formal protocol from now on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use the formal protocol?